# Создание метода put() в наследуемом по HashMap классе

Tags: java

Здесь я хочу создать класс-синглтон, который одновременно выполняет функции Map. Ключом является String, содержимым-- ArrayList. Так же мне требуется два метода put(), первый принимает переменные типа String и double, второй принимает четыре переменных типа String, double, int, double.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SuperSingl extends HashMap{
    private static SuperSingl singleton;
    private ArrayList ar;

        private SuperSingl(){}

       public static  SuperSingl getInstance( ) {
          if (singleton == null)
              singleton=new SuperSingl();
          return singleton;
       }


     public SuperSingl put(String key, ArrayList value) {
         if (key == null)
             return putForNullKey(value);
         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
         int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
         for (Entry<String, ArrayList> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
             Object k;
             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
                 ArrayList oldValue = e.value;
                 e.value = value;
                 e.recordAccess(this);
                 return oldValue;
             }
         }

         modCount++;
         addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
         return null;
     }


       public void put(String s, double f1) {
           ar.set(0, f1);
           SuperSingl.getInstance().put(s, ar);
       }

       public void put(String s, double f1, int i, double f2) {
           ar.add(0, f1);
           ar.add(1, i);
           ar.add(2, f2);
           SuperSingl.getInstance().put(s, ar);

    }
}
```

Как правильно в методе put() обратиться к переменным с наследуемого класса, чтобы код работал?

Comment: Вы ни от кого не наследуетесь. Для наследования используйте ключевое слово `extends`.

Comment: Опечатался. Но даже если есть наследование, то как решить эту проблему?

Comment: К каким переменным вы хотите обратиться?

Comment: Ко всем переменным с класса HashMap в методе put()